# Remote installation on linux without using ssh

Tags: linux, installation, system-administration

I want to run a script on a remote machine without using ssh.. Is it possible?
If yes then what all available options are there in linux?

Here are few details regarding the same.

1) On my machine i have a script, say a.sh, which performs installation of few packages. (such as lsof, ntp, vim etc).

2) I need to copy this script to the remote machine, and i want to execute it over there. (So that those packages get installated on to those machines.

3) what i am trying to achieve is if i have to do these packages installation on n no of machines, then with this mechanism i can automate this part.

Is there any preexisting infrastructure in linux which can help me doing this without ssh? (ssh to these virtual machines/remote counterparts is not possible)

Cheers,
Placid/

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu one has this form of remote package management availible , although on a personal level I simply prefer to scp / ssh exec scripts like this when deploying a change set to multiple machines .

Comment: i read about expect scripts  but those also use ssh internally.. Between what is that infrastructures name in Ubuntu one?

Comment: Re reading your post it states that ssh is not possible , is there a specific reason as to why ? Is it a simple tunnelling/Nat issue ?

Comment: ssh is not possible because these machines are secure machines, and the owners of these machines are not willing to give ssh access to anyone..
I had written a c program to fork ssh and control its execution using pipes. But that requires ssh, and the owners do not want to grant the ssh access to anyone..
I know its strange but it is like this only.
I am programatically unable to think of any solution thats why thought of asking it here...

Comment: You will have to elaborate further on your use of the word secure . Since ssh stands for "secure shell", a properly configured ssh daemon is by far the safest way to access a machine or its contents.